# Is "as can be" a correct phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I used this in my poem about war and peace:

> "Why must we have war?
>
> When we could live peacefully or,
>
> Find a door,
>
> That leads to not a country that is war-tore,
>
> ---
>
> But one that has peace,
>
> And one that’s peace could never cease.
>
> And with inhabitants whose peace could never decrease,
>
> And it would be a masterpiece.
>
> ---
>
> Peace and war have something common you see,
>
> Both can start from a tiny action **as can be**,"

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: No, but you can say "an action as tiny as can be"

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound correct to me. As @Timinycricket mentioned, "an action as tiny as can be" would work.

The general structure would be something like "[noun] as [adjective] as can be".